# WCF Error: 'There was an error on processing web request: Status code 400(BadRequest)' Is it Message Size Error?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

So I have a WCF service which I am tried to upload a `byte[]` to. I can get through to my service calling a default `Hello()` method I have implemented and see some logging. But can't upload my byte array. It looks like the call doesn't even reach the service.

If I upload a Byte[] of length 289160 I get the following error returned:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.

And Inner Exception:

> {System.Net.WebException: There was an error on processing web
>   request: Status code 400(BadRequest): Bad Request   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+HttpChannelRequestAsyncResult.WaitEnd
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.EndRequest
>   (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.DoProcess
>   (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Process
>   (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 }

But when I upload a byte[] of length 0 it gets through to my service and I see logging.

My Binding is:

```
BasicHttpBinding uploadBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
```

with the same binding replicated Service side...

I'm guessing this is something to do with the message received size or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding:

```
<maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" openTimeout="00:10:00"
sendTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">

<readerQuotas maxDepth="10485760" maxStringContentLength="10485760"
maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="10485760"
maxNameTableCharCount="10485760" />
```

to my binding in my Web.config on my service side.